# How do I add a new replicated table to a SQL Server 2005 DB that is in merge replication?

Tags: sql-server, replication

We have merge replication set up over a distributed environment (50 to 1500km between offices) for a SQL Server 2005 database of about 350Gb.  We now need to add a couple of new tables that must also be in replication, but without pushing the new snapshot to all the subscribers.  Is this possible, and if so, what would be the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sp_addmergearticle - Adds an article to an existing merge publication. This stored procedure is executed at the Publisher on the publication database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174329.aspx

Comment: Sorry but sp_addmergearticle will not work in this case if @force_reinit_subscription is set to false. Reinitialising replication is then mandatory.